# How can I view network adapter associated to docker container

Tags: docker

How can I view network adapter associated to container.

I launched an application that starts 50 docker containers and created 50 "virtual" network adapters on my Ubuntu 18.04 system.

I can view network adapters with `ifconfig -a`. It shows ipv6 but not ipv4.
I can also view docker container ipv4 with `docker inspect`, but not ipv6.

I haven't figured out a way to associate a network adapter with a docker container.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42712864/7338534

Answer (score 1):

You can check the interface ifindex of the veth pair:

```
brctl show docker0
```

To see the veth interfaces in the docker bridge, Now using this script you can see which interface your container is using:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(ip link list | awk -F '@' '/veth/ {split($2,a,":"); print a[1]}' | sed 's/if//g');do
  for dock in $(docker ps --quiet);do
    dock_index=$(docker exec -ti $dock cat /sys/class/net/eth0/ifindex | sed 's/\r$//')
    if [[ $i == $dock_index ]]; then
       echo "$i $dock"
    fi
  done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this command to find you docker network id:

```
docker network ls --no-trunc

NETWORK ID                                                         NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
1849dpjmcnj7ckw4q2svhvj4r                                          base_default        overlay             swarm
```

And then inspect it:

```
docker inspect <container_name> | grep "1849dpjmcnj7ckw4q2svhvj4r"
                        "Target": "1849dpjmcnj7ckw4q2svhvj4r",
                    "NetworkID": "1849dpjmcnj7ckw4q2svhvj4r",
```